# Problem With Using Elements Of An String

Tags: c#

i have this code for example:

```
string i = "100";

if(i[1]==0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok");
}
```

and I thought I should get "ok" but it doesnt work. What is `i[1]` here?

Comment: For this situation, `i[1]` is the character `0`. You're comparing a `char` against an `int`. The number equivalent of the character `0` is 48. Since `0 == 48` is `false`, no alert is displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison is using the wrong type. When you use an indexer with a string, the result is a `char`. Your if statement is using an `int`. You need to change your code to:

```
if(i[1] == '0')
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're comparing a string to an integer.

Try `if (i[1] == '0')`.

Answer (score 2):

`i[1]` is a **char** of `'0'` (Unicode U+0030), which is different than (int) `0`.

Answer (score 1):

char i[0] is compared against an integer

Answer (score 0):

`i[1]` is the second character in the string, as arrays in c#  are zero-based.

Comment: That's not what OP was asking. i[1] is a perfectly valid index into his string of length 3.